# nbconvert: exporting to another directory?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm wondering if it's possible to export a Jupyter notebook to a different directory than the same directory as the notebook itself? I'm using this to build HTML versions of the notebooks, and I'd like them to reside under `docs/` in my GitHub repo (this is to take advantage of GH-pages).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NBConvert's --output-dir argument does this: [https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

You can use it from the command line or from within a Jupyter notebook.

*Command line:*

```
jupyter nbconvert --output-dir='./docs' --to html my_notebook_to_be_converted.ipynb
```

*From within a Jupyter Notebook cell:*

```
!jupyter nbconvert --output-dir='./docs' --to html my_notebook_to_be_converted.ipynb
```

Note that you don't need to use "--to html" to convert a notebook to html because the default output format is html. I've included the argument solely for clarity.

Comment: From within a Jupyter notebook, can you "self" `nbconvert` that notebook?

Comment: Sure. Just precede the command with a !

If you just want it next to the existing notebook you can leave out the output-dir argument.

    !jupyter nbconvert --to html "my_notebook_to_be_converted.ipynb"

Comment: Notebook version can generate an infinite loop if the `--execute` option is given